# Drag Cursor not showing on OSX

Tags: java, macos, drag-and-drop, cursor

We have a large Java app that is used on both Windows and OSX.
We do custom Drag and Drop between 2 of our JTables.

On Windows, this works perfectly.  The custom cursor is displayed as you drag over the target JTable.

On the Mac, the custom cursor is never displayed.  Instead a gray rectangle (border only) is displayed when you start dragging.  This rectangle is the width of the table column, and the height of the table.  Our logging is showing that the dragOver() and dropActionChanged() methods are getting called, and we are setting the custom cursor.  It just never gets displayed.

If I disable our custom cursor code, the same box is displayed - but it has the Circle/slash icon in the middle as well.

I want to get rid of the weird box, and display the custom cursor.

Excerpts from the code:

```
    private class FileTransferHandler extends TransferHandler {

    private static final long           serialVersionUID        = 1L;
    private final Logger                log             = LogManager.getLogger();
    private final CursorDragSourceListener  dragSourceListener  = new CursorDragSourceListener();

    // Left out the Drop handling code that was here

    @Override
    public int getSourceActions( final JComponent c) {
        log.debug("FileTransferHandler.getSourceAction: ");
        return COPY | MOVE;
    }

    @Override
    protected Transferable createTransferable( final JComponent c) {
        log.debug("FileTransferHandler.createTransferable:");
        List<iFilePage> pages = new ArrayList<iFilePage>();

        // Left out the code that builds the pages list

        DragSource.getDefaultDragSource().addDragSourceListener(dragSourceListener);
        dragSourceListener.setCursorChoice(pages.size() == 1);

        return new FilePageTransferable(pages);
    }

    @Override
    protected void exportDone(  final JComponent c,
                        final Transferable t,
                        final int action) {
        log.debug("FileTransferHandler.exportDone: {}", action, t);
        tblFixed.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
        DragSource.getDefaultDragSource().removeDragSourceListener(dragSourceListener);
        return;
    }
}

private static class CursorDragSourceListener implements DragSourceListener {
    private Cursor  singlePage      = null;
    private Cursor  multiPage       = null;
    private Cursor  badSinglePage   = null;
    private Cursor  useCursor       = null;
    private boolean useSingle       = false;

    public CursorDragSourceListener() {
        Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        URL url;
        String name;
        Image img;

        url = FileUtils.getResourceURL("/images/page.png");
        name = "DragPage";
        img = toolkit.createImage(url);
        singlePage = toolkit.createCustomCursor(img, new Point(16, 16), name);

        url = FileUtils.getResourceURL("/images/badpage_stack.png");
        name = "DragBadPage";
        img = toolkit.createImage(url);
        badSinglePage = toolkit.createCustomCursor(img, new Point(16, 16), name);

        url = FileUtils.getResourceURL("/images/page_stack.png");
        name = "DragPageStack";
        img = toolkit.createImage(url);
        multiPage = toolkit.createCustomCursor(img, new Point(16, 16), name);

        return;
    }

    public void setCursorChoice( final boolean single) {
        log.debug("CursorDragSourceListener.setCursorChoice: {}", single);
        useSingle = single;
        if (useSingle) {
            useCursor = singlePage;
        } else {
            useCursor = multiPage;
        }
        return;
    }

    @Override
    public void dropActionChanged( final DragSourceDragEvent dsde) {
        log.debug("CursorDragSourceListener.dropActionChanged: {}", dsde.getDropAction(), useSingle);

        if (dsde.getDropAction() == 2) {
            if (!useSingle) {
                useCursor = badSinglePage;
            } else {
                useCursor = singlePage;
            }

        } else {
            if (useSingle) {
                useCursor = singlePage;
            } else {
                useCursor = multiPage;
            }
        }

        dsde.getDragSourceContext().setCursor(useCursor);
        return;
    }

    @Override
    public void dragOver( final DragSourceDragEvent dsde) {

        try {
            Object x = dsde.getDragSourceContext().getTransferable()
                        .getTransferData(DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor);
            log.trace("CursorDragSourceListener.dragOver: {}", (x != null) ? x.getClass().getSimpleName() : "null");

            if (x instanceof ArrayList) {
                dsde.getDragSourceContext().setCursor(useCursor);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("CursorDragSourceListener.dragOver:", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void dragExit( final DragSourceEvent dse) {
    }

    @Override
    public void dragEnter( final DragSourceDragEvent dsde) {
    }

    @Override
    public void dragDropEnd( final DragSourceDropEvent dsde) {
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

After a bunch more checking and analysis, it turns out that our Custom Selection Model was causing this problem on OSX.
We have a selection model that allows you to select multiple individual cells, not just whole rows.
So the getMinSelectionindex() and getMaxSelectionIndex() methods returned dummy data, since we never used them.

That works fine on MS Win, but apparently the OSX drag and drop for JTable uses those calls.

After modifying our code to return reasonable values, the selection box is no longer as tall as the table.

The custom cursors appear most of the time, but still randomly disappear for no apparent reason.